# CLLocationManager not calling any delegate methods

Tags: iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager

First off, the disclaimer is I'm targeting iOS 5, so that very well may be the source of my issues, but if not...

I'm trying to write a simple class that manages location updates through CoreLocation. However, I see some pretty strange behavior. I have a custom class which basically wraps CLLocationManager and the delegate methods. This is the interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol CLZipCodeFetcherDelegate
@optional - (void)didReceiveZipCode:(NSString *)zipCode;
@end

@interface CLZipCodeFetcher : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    id <CLZipCodeFetcherDelegate> delegate;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (strong, readwrite) id <CLZipCodeFetcherDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, read write) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)getZipCode;

@end
```

and the implementation (ignore the zip code related stuff- that's what the class is eventually meant to do, but right now I'm just trying to get some coordinates back from CoreLocation):

```
#import "CLZipCodeFetcher.h"

@implementation CLZipCodeFetcher

@synthesize delegate, locationManager;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f; // we don't need to be any more accurate than 10m
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
        self.locationManager.purpose = @"Retrieve zip code";
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)getZipCode {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"Received location");
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Location failed");
}

@end
```

And then I initialize an instance of the class in my view controller and call the method:

```
CLZipCodeFetcher *zipCodeFetcher = [[CLZipCodeFetcher alloc] init];
[zipCodeFetcher getZipCode];
```

Now, when I run this, the app takes a moment to load, and then pops up the alert dialog asking for permission to let the app use location services. However, as soon as it appears, it immediately disappears (too fast to let me hit the allow or deny button), and nothing happens (no delegate methods are called). If I then go into the Location Settings of the device, it indeed shows 'Off' for my app. When I turn it on manually from that screen and then go to try the app again, no alert dialog appears, but still nothing happens. Neither of my debug messages are logged. The behavior is the same on both the simulator and my iPhone 4.

So basically, anyone have any idea why? I've looked through all the similar threads, and many issues were related to memory management, but I don't think that'd be a problem here since ARC should be managing my CLLocationManager object, right?

P.S. Also, I did add the CoreLocation framework to my project, and I get no code errors or warnings, but is there anything else I need to do before using CoreLocation in my app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ARC is deallocating your newly created object after the getZipCode method call.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it- turning automatic reference counting off fixes the issue. Any idea how to keep it from deallocating the location manager object?

Comment: the compiler will generate a `[zipCodeFetcher release]` just after your call. Use a property to maintain a strong reference to it.

Comment: I don't get it: he -does- have a strong reference to the location manager. Why would it deallocate it?

Comment: Hi greg, he doesn't have a strong reference to `CLZipCodeFetcher`, so the entire graph is deallocated after the method call.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ARC yet so I'm not sure of your syntax in the header (readwrite vs. read write).

But I would put an NSLog(@" my loc manager is %@", self.locationManager); inside of getZipCode just to make sure you've got one and it's not being released before it has a chance to do anything.

Comment: Yep, it does log what appears to be a valid CLLocationManager object. I also tried (nonatomic, retain) for the location manager property, but still nothing.

Comment: Hmm.  The only other thing I can think of would be to fiddle with the configuration, set   self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;  and     self.locManager.distanceFilter  =  kCLDistanceFilterNone;